# How do I pass multiple outputs of a python script to a shell bash script?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, variables

I need a python script to calculate some numerical values which, in next step, are passed to another shell bash script to continue the following computations. Say the python script is `./python.py` which is:

```
import numpy as np
def func(arg1, arg2):
    ...
    result1=0.111
    result2=0.222
    result3=0.333
    return result1, result2, result3
arg1=1
arg2=2
result1, result2, result3 = func(arg1, arg2)
print(result1, result2, result3)
```

And the bash script is `./bash.sh` which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
~/.conda/envs/vegetation/bin/python split_nc_domain.py
...(following part which needs result1, result2, result3)
```

So how can I pass the `result1, result2, result3` to the `./bash.sh`? I knew that if I only have one output I can use following commands:
`` VARIABLE=`~/.conda/envs/vegetation/bin/python split_nc_domain.py` ``  or `VARIABLE=$(~/.conda/envs/vegetation/bin/python split_nc_domain.py)`. But how can I do it for multiple outputs from python? Thanks!

---

updates:

Somebody in the comments suggests me to use `x=($(~/.conda/envs/vegetation/bin/python split_nc_domain.py))`. But what can I do next step? is there anything like `x[0], x[1], x[2]` to check that? by `echo $x` I can only see the first value `0.111` which is the value of the first variable.

Comment: Please add output of ./python.py to your question.

Comment: The generic approach is to separate the values of the output by a delimiter that will never appear in the values, then use that delimiter in `bash` to read the values, e.g. `IFS=<delimiter> read -r var1 var2 var3`. If you use linefeed as delimiter you can use `IFS='' read -r line` in a loop

Comment: Hi @Cyrus, what do you mean by "output of ./python.py"?

Comment: I added the example values of result1, result2 and result3 in the problem descriptions. They are of float64 type.

Comment: Since the "result" is just a bunch of numbers, I would write them to stdout (separated by a space). In bash, you fetch this output and transfer the numbers into a bash array.

Comment: Hi @user1934428, thanks but how can I "fetch this output and transfer the numbers into a bash array"?

Comment: `x=($(p))` tuns the command `p` in a child process, collects its standard output, and, after applying word splitting, stores it into the array `x`.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, could you be much more specific? say, how to use the method in my case? and how to separate the values to different variables in bash script? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @user1934428, thanks but I tried and got that x only contains the first value...by type ```echo $x```, I can just see the value of result1, which is 0.111.

Comment: Here are two examples illustrating my two suggestions handling different output formats : https://ideone.com/EAGBnZ (linefeed as delimiter) ; https://ideone.com/SYEg45 (non-linefeed character as delimiter, `;` in the example)

Comment: @XuShan : Please use _questions_ at  _Stackoverflow_ to ask this, and not _comments_. Ask only one problem in a single question.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), in particular the section titled _Get answers to practical, detailed questions_. The reason is that SO-comments are not searchable.

Comment: Hi @user1934428, but I thought this is related to my problem and is an issue of my problem...because by only using ```x=($(p))```, I don't know how to solve my problem...maybe could you be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Aaron, thanks for your suggestion! I will take a look at that!

Comment: Hi @user1934428, could you be much more clear with your answer? I tried with ```x=($(p))```, but I don't know how to do the next step. With ```echo $x```, I can only see the first answer. If I tried ```x=$(p)``` and ```echo $x```, I can see all the variables. But I don't know how to separate them...

Comment: Hi @Aaron, thanks but I don't know whether I understand you correctly...in your example you already assign the value to ```var1 var2 var3```? but my question is just how to assign the value to them...and the values come from the results of python script...

Comment: `read -r first second third < <(~/whoknowswhere/my_python_script.py)`

Comment: @XuShan I'm answering to the bash part of your question : I'm giving you ways to split the output of a command (in your case, your python script) in bash in order to retrieve it into 3 variables. In my ideone samples, I've provided a specific input ; if your python output looks like one of those inputs, then you can use the code I wrote in that example to split your python script's output into 3 and write it into 3 variables

Comment: @XuShan You'll probably find [this sample](https://ideone.com/0xTFTE) easier to understand since it reproduces what I assume is your python's script output format. A problem is the need to use `< <(...)` to feed the command's output into `read` ; it's advanced bash scripting and I'm not confortable trying to explain why it's necessary.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, thanks a lot for your reply! I will take a look at the sample. I will comment your response if I got any further questions. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, especially since it's not much of an answer. I'll see if I can come up with a full answer any time soon, but I'm currently short on time.

Comment: @XuShan I've posted an answer that documents a more basic way to split a single-line output into multiple variables. I might expand my answer later to document the `IFS=' ' read -r var1 var2 var3 < <(command)` syntax I was talking about in the comments, but I think it's just making things more complicated than they need to be in your context

Comment: @XuShan : If you have an array `x`, the element with index `i` is retrieved by `"${x[$i]}"`. Indexing starts by zero. If you want to pass all elements to some other program, you can write `"${x[*]}"`. Please get familiar with using arrays before trying something. See [here](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/arrays/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your python script can't be changed, we have to work from bash with the following format :

```
first_value second_value third_value
```

where single spaces delimit three fields. Note that values containing spaces would break that format (creating additional fields), but in the context of numbers printed by `python` that seems unlikely if at all possible.

A basic way to retrieve those three values separately is to store the whole value inside a text variable, then execute three commands to retrieve the three values separately :

```
whole_output="$(./python.py)"
first_value="$(echo "$whole_output" | cut -d' ' -f1)"
second_value="$(echo "$whole_output" | cut -d' ' -f2)"
third_value="$(echo "$whole_output" | cut -d' ' -f3)"
```

This relies on `$(command substitution)` which is interpreted first, executes the command it contains and is then replaced by its output before the command that encloses it is executed.
For the first line for instance, first your python script would be executed, then the command would become `whole_output="first_value second_value third_value"` which is a basic assignment.
The `cut` command used lets you specify a delimiter (a space here) and the index of a field you want to retrieve.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/0jTbeA).

If you have a lot of values, writing one line per value and invoking one command per value becomes problematic. In this case you will either want to use `read` or `readarray`, where the first one reads into multiple variables and the second reads into an array :

```
IFS=' ' read -r var1 var2 var3 ... varN < <(./python.py)
```

or

```
readarray -d' ' array < <(./python.py)
# can access individual values with ${array[0]}, ${array[1]}, etc. 
# or list all values with ${array[@]}
```

You're probably wondering why we're using the `< <(...)` syntax to feed data into read/readarray. Usually you'd simply use a pipe to do that. The problem with pipes is that, quoting `man bash`, "Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)." and that subshells have their own scopes, which means changes on variables aren't visible outside of the pipeline.
The `< <(...)` syntax on the other hand lets you feed the output of the command it contains to the input of any command without creating any subshell by using what's called process substitution.